# ParDo vs FlatMap in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a difference between `ParDo` and `FlatMap` in Dataflow / Apache Beam?

I think both apply a function to each element of the incoming `PCollection`, and return the iterable; but I imagine there must be some difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FlatMap` is a simpler operation [built as you might expect from `ParDo`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/FlatMapElements.java#L131). If this fits your needs, it is a good choice.

`ParDo` is a lower-level building block of element-wise computation that has additional capabilities like [side inputs](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.java#L581), [multiple output collections](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.java#L610), [access to the current window](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.java#L85), some really low level callbacks for starting and committing bundle of elements, and more.

In practice, many uses of `FlatMap` and `ParDo` end up with a similar code bulk, but in my opinion it is most readable to use the simplest (highest level) transform available.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. 

Though FWIW the python examples use `FlatMap` with side inputs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/. `ParDo` for the others as your suggest though