# Apache Beam:- Unexpected output of Pardo

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

As a newbie, I created a pipeline with a couple of Transform functions, after having input from a file, it turns the code to lowercase. When I passed that outcome to the next stage it does not appear as a single string but multiple characters. Below is my code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class ToLower(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        #return [{'Data': element.lower()}]
        return element.lower()


class ToReverse(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(element)
        return element


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_file = 'news.txt'
    options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
        r = (
            p | beam.io.ReadFromText(in_file)
            | beam.ParDo(ToLower())
            | beam.ParDo(ToReverse())
        )
```

Assuming the content of `news.txt` is below:

> Coronavirus cases in Pakistan doubled in one day with total tally at
>   106 on Monday

When I run the above code it prints the following instead of the reverse:

```
c
o
r
o
n
a
v
i
r
u
s

c
a
s
e
s

i
n

p
a
k
i
s
t
a
n

d
o
u
b
l
e
d

i
n

o
n
e

d
a
y

w
i
t
h

t
o
t
a
l

t
a
l
l
y

a
t

1
0
6

o
n

m
o
n
d
a
y
```

And when I change the return in `ToLower` to `return [{'Data': element.lower()}]` then it returns as a single string line. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Apache Beam Documentation (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/):

[image]

What this means is that the Beam framework looks at the output elements and tries to actively convert the output elements as a zero or more elements.

A Python string is a sequence of Unicode code points.
Therefore, even though the lower() function returns a single element, that gets converted into a sequence of elements by the Beam framework.

Hope this clarifies.

**Few other SO posts that are related:**

[Difference between beam.ParDo and beam.Map in the output type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912918/difference-between-beam-pardo-and-beam-map-in-the-output-type) 
[ParDo vs FlatMap in Apache Beam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647566/pardo-vs-flatmap-in-apache-beam)